# QT mapFromGlobal not 100% accurate

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5

I'm using pyqt5 and I'm trying to do a custom context menu for a combo box inside of a table widget. I've successfully done this with a table widget without a combo box inside but I'm a little stuck now. I don't have access to the combo box that requested the context menu so I can't map from it to the table. I've now tried mapping the global cursor position to the table and it comes close, but it isn't exactly the same so I end up getting the wrong row/column combination. I tried this on a non-combo box cell so I could compare the real position to the position I mapped from the cursor:

```
cursorPos = QCursor.pos()
print('\nCursor pos')
print(cursorPos)
mappedFromGlobal = self.table.mapFromGlobal(QCursor.pos())
print('\nMapped from global')
print(mappedFromGlobal)
print('\nGiven pos')
print(pos)
```

This is the output I get from the above code:

```
Cursor pos
PyQt5.QtCore.QPoint(933, 442)
Mapped from global
PyQt5.QtCore.QPoint(542, 159)
Given pos
PyQt5.QtCore.QPoint(519, 133)
```

The Given pos is the real position of the cell that the customContextMenuRequested signal gives me and as you can see the mapped position is close, but not exact.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All QAbstractScrollArea based widgets, including item views, use a *viewport* (see the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractscrollarea.html#details)) to show the scrollable contents, and that viewport can have [*margins*](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractscrollarea.html#setViewportMargins).

For item views, those margins are automatically set to display the headers, and receiving mouse events in the area you get those events already mapped to the viewport. If you want to track a global position, instead, you need to *manually* map it to the viewport:

```
mappedFromGlobal = self.table.viewport().mapFromGlobal(QCursor.pos())
```